# How do I refactor this sailboat transform to solve for apparent wind direction for my sailboat plotting algorithm?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, physics, programming

The core problem I would like assistance with is this:

How do I refactor this formula to transpose $a$?

$$\sin(a_0)\sin(a) \biggl(\frac{ \sin(\frac{a}{2})}{\sin(a_0 - a)}\biggr) ^2 = VW \cdot \eta$$

For more context, please read on.

I'm in a little over my head, and may be mixing up some terms, so please forgive my ignorance. I am attempting to write a route plotting algorithm that calculates a sailboat's $VMG$ (a measure of how optimal a sailboat's heading or direction of sail is) using live wind velocity and wind direction. The goal is to give the user a tool for optimizing pathfinding in the context of sailing. VMG is calculated using this formula:

$V$ = boat speed  
$x$ = angle of wind relative to the front of the boat

$$VMG = V \cdot \cos(x)$$

---

In order to calculate boat speed from wind speed, I plan to use this formula, which is apparently widely accepted:

$VW$ = wind velocity 
$a_0$ = true wind angle relative to the front of the boat 
$a$ = apparent wind angle (i.e. wind generated by movement of the boat)

$$VB = VW \cdot \frac{\sin(a_0 - a)}{\sin(a)}$$

In order to solve this, I need to find $a$.

---

[This article](https://sites.google.com/site/yoavraz2/sailingboatspeedvs.windspeed) by Yoav Raz posits that *a* can be found by solving for it in his sailboat transform:

VW= wind velocity 
$a_0$ = true wind angle relative to the front of the boat 
$a$ = apparent wind angle (i.e. wind generated by movement of the boat) 
$\eta$ = a complex measure of the boat's resistance to acceleration which for this purpose I will assume to be a low, constant number around 0.01)

$$\sin(a_0) * \sin(a) * \biggl(\frac{ \sin( \frac{a}{2})}{ sin(a_0 - a)}\biggr) ^2 = VW \cdot \eta$$

In practice, I will know the wind velocity and true wind angle, and as I said will be assuming $\eta$. Here is where the trouble starts: I am not very good at math anymore, and I find myself at a loss as to how to refactor this formula for my purposes. In order to use this formula in my algorithm, I need to refactor it into an expression that isolates $a$ given the other parameters( i.e. $a=f(x)$ ).

I've tried to refactor it by using trigonometric identities, which I think is the right path. The farthest I've gotten is this:

$$\sin(a_0) \sin(a)  \biggl( \frac{\sin(\frac{a}{2})}{\sin(a_0)\cos(a)-\cos(a_0)\sin(a)}\biggr)^2 = VW\cdot \eta$$

I know I'm kind of asking "please teach me trigonometry and calculus," so my apologies for that. I'm just hoping that even if I'm barking up the wrong tree that someone can help point me in the  right direction.

Edit:
It now occurs to me that the solution might be to simply iteratively attempt to solve this by trying inputs for *a* and attempting to solve for 1. The Raz article suggests doing this and starting with values slightly below *a0*. I could write a model to evaluate this expression with decreasing values until it arrives at a value *a* such that both sides resolve to 1.

Here are some more relevant resources to this problem space, if you would like to understand a bit more background around this topic:

[The Physics of Sailing](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/%7Ejw/sailing.html#:%7E:text=The%20wind%20is%20faster%20than,wind%2C%20even%20with%20a%20spinnaker.)

[Sailboat speed Vs. wind speed](https://sites.google.com/site/yoavraz2/sailingboatspeedvs.windspeed)

[Velocity Made Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_made_good)

[Polar Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_diagram_(sailing))

[Apparent Wind Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_wind#:%7E:text=Apparent%20wind%20in%20sailing,-In%20sailing%2C%20apparent&text=A%20true%20wind%20coming%20from,craft%20and%20the%20true%20wind.)

Comment: Trying some specific numbers in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+%28sin%28x%2F2%29%29%5E2+%2F+%28sin%281-x%29%29%5E2+%3D+0.8) gives an exact answer involving a root of an eighth-degree polynomial, which is a strong clue that there is not going to be a good way to write $a = f(x).$ Some sort of iterative method is called for. There are various algorithms to try.

Comment: @DavidK. It is a quartic.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was referring to this expression from Wolfram Alpha (which is not always as clever as possible), `root of sin^2(1) x^8 + 8 cos(1) sin(1) x^7 + (16 cos^2(1) - 12 sin^2(1)) x^6 + (20 - 56 cos(1) sin(1)) x^5 + (-32 cos^2(1) + 38 sin^2(1)) x^4 + (-20 + 56 cos(1) sin(1)) x^3 + (16 cos^2(1) - 12 sin^2(1)) x^2 - 8 cos(1) sin(1) x + sin^2(1)`

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I see the quartics in your second answer. I think the most valuable part of each answer is in the approximation techniques you specify, since even with the quartic this still seems like a problem best addressed by numerical methods.

Comment: @DavidK. In fact it took me time because I really thought about a possible octic; this is why my first answer was jsut about approximations. What I like is the second change of variable which makes the coefficients so simple ! On the worked example, just for the fun, I asked for the solution of the quartic : is was about a mile long ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks to you both! I can see I am truly in over my head haha. For my purposes, I think that the first solution suggested by @ClaudeLeibovici is a better fit mostly because I'm working on a proof of concept. Were I designing a more rigorous simulation I think Claude's second answer would be the place to start, but clearly I have some studying to do if I go that route. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: May be, you could accept one of them, clicking the green arrow. By the way, I still work the problem. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is $$\sin(a_0) \, \sin(a) \, \biggl(\frac{ \sin( \frac{a}{2})}{ \sin(a_0 - a)}\biggr) ^2 = VW \, \eta$$ For personal conveniency, I shall change notations : $b=a_0$ , $k=VW\, \eta$ and I shall consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(a)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \sin (a) \sin (b)-k \sin ^2(a-b)$$
For $a=b$, we have
$$f(b)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \sin ^2(b)$$
$$f'(b)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \sin (b) (1+2 \cos (b))$$
$$f''(b)=\frac{1}{4} (2 \cos (b)+\cos (2 b)-2 \cos (3 b)-8 k-1)$$
$$f'''(b)=-\sin (b)-\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 b)+\sin (3 b)$$

Assuming that $a$ is close to $b$, let us make **one** single interation of Halley method to get
$$a_{(1)}=b-\frac{2 f(b)\, f'(b)}{2 f'(b)^2-f(b)\, f''(b)}$$

Just to make a test, trying for $b=\frac \pi 6$ and $k=0.5$, the above  would give
$$a=\frac{\pi }{6}-\frac{30 \sqrt{3}-22}{277}\approx 0.415434 $$ while the "exact" solution is $0.399521$. In degrees, $b=30^{\circ}$ leads to an estimate of $a=23.8026^{\circ}$ while the "exact" solution is $a=22.8909^{\circ}$.

If, this is not sufficiently accurate, make **one** single interation of Householder method to get
$$a_{(1)}=b+\frac{3 f(b) \left(f(b)\, f''(b)-2 f'(b)^2\right)}{f(b)^2 f'''(b)+6 f'(b)^3-6
   f(b)\, f'(b)\, f''(b)}$$
For the worked example, this gives
$$a=\frac{\pi }{6}-\frac{7209 \sqrt{3}-6846}{43739} \approx 0.394644 $$ corresponding to $22.6114^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to make a second answer.*

Using the same notations as above, let $\color{red}{a=2\sin^{-1}(x)}$ and expand. Now, we face the problem of the zero's of function
$$f(x)=4 x \sqrt{1-x^2} \sin (b) \left(2 k \left(1-2 x^2\right) \cos (b)+x^2\right)+$$ $$k
   \left(8 x^4-8 x^2+1\right) \cos (2 b)-k$$Isolating the square root and squaring, we get a quartic equation in $y=x^2$

$$A_0+A_1y+A_2y^2+A_3 y^3+A_4y^4=0$$ where
$$A_0=4 k^2 \sin ^2(b) \qquad A_1=-32 k^2$$ $$A_2=16 k \csc ^2(b) (-k \cos (2 b)-\cos (b)+\cos (3 b)+5 k)$$
$$A_3=-16 \left(8 k^2 \csc ^2(b)-12 k \cos (b)+1\right)$$
$$A_4=8 \csc ^2(b) \left(-8 k \sin (b) \sin (2 b)-\cos (2 b)+8 k^2+1\right)$$ which means that $\color{red}{\text{there is an analytical solution to the problem}}$ with very nasty radicals.

Applied to the worked example, this would give (the ridiculous number od decimals is on purpose)
$$y=0.03937627700155306953468549235033823816779707297868$$
$$x=0.19843456604521569476116634159797359301513019509245$$
$$a=0.39952093243881675034376955944379221762172468816265$$
$$\color{blue}{a=22.8908632558755028037653673980262663277334485138902^{\circ}}$$

**Edit**

Something simpler could be obtained using $\color{red}{a=b-\sin ^{-1}(2 x)}$. This time, we end adain with a quartic in $x$
$$B_0+B_1x+B_2x^2+B_3 x^3+B_4x^4=0$$ where
$$B_0= \sin ^6(b)\qquad B_1=-4 \sin ^5(b)\qquad B_2=-16 k \sin ^2(b) \cos (b)$$
$$B_3=-8 \sin (b) (4 k \cos (b)+\cos (2 b)-1)\qquad B_4=-8 \left(-8 k \sin (b) \sin (2 b)-\cos (2 b)+8 k^2+1\right)$$ where the coefficients are much simpler.

The solution can be *approximated* using the $[1,4]$ Padé approximant leading to
$$x \sim \frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}$$
$$\text{numerator}=-72 \sin ^5(b)-16 k \left(\sin ^3(b) (31 \cos (b)+\cos (3 b))\right)-16 k^2 (\sin
   (b) (3 \cos (2 b)+5))$$
$$\text{denominator}=-192 \sin ^4(b)-128 k \left(\sin ^2(b) (19 \cos (b)+\cos (3 b))\right)-128 k^2 (7
   \cos (2 b)+9)$$

For the worked example, this would lead to
$$x=\frac{4068 \sqrt{3}-785}{100432}$$
$$a=\frac \pi 6-\sin ^{-1}(2 x)=0.39860$$ to be compared to the exact $a=0.39952$. This corresponds to an error of $0.05^{\circ}$.

We could , without any problem, continue with Padé approximants of higher order for a still better accuracy. For example, the next one would give
$$x=\frac{3830+377 \sqrt{3}}{72608}$$
$$a=\frac \pi 6-\sin ^{-1}(2 x)=0.39980$$ which corresponds to an error smaller than $0.02^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Another approach*

Consider
$$f(a)=\sin(b) \, \sin(a) \, \biggl(\frac{ \sin( \frac{a}{2})}{ \sin(b - a)}\biggr) ^2 $$ Make again ${a=b-\sin ^{-1}(2 x)}$ to define $g(x)$.

Assuming that $x$ is small, expand $g(x)$ as a series around $x=0$ to get
$$g(x)=\frac{\sin ^2(b) (1-\cos (b))}{8 x^2}+O\left(\frac 1x\right)$$ and then an approximate solution
$$x_0=\sin (b)\sqrt{\frac{ (1-\cos (b))}{8 k}}$$

For the worked example, this gives $$x_0=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\implies a=\frac{\pi }{6}-\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)\sim 0.339549$$ Now, Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & 0.339549 \\
 1 & 0.393787 \\
 2 & 0.399457 \\
 3 & 0.399521
\end{array}
\right)$$